# Angularjs with ng-repeat is generating the same id for multiple elements of the same type

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an html page where i have an object 'Message' having a property 'Properties' which is an array of objects. The problem is when I'm using 'ng-repeat' to iterate over 'Message.Properties' items to render certain custom elements i created with angularjs which by its turn generate an id, i get the same id for the elements of the same type. here's a sample of my code:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="property in Message.Properties">
...
  <div ngm-if="(property.Type == 9)">                            
    <sdk:selectbox name="property.Title" row="" datafield="property.Value"
      options="property.ValueCollection" displayfield="Value" valuefield="Key"
      mandatory="property.isMandatory" labeled="property.Title" multiple="">
    </neolynk:selectbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

To reformulate, when the element "sdk:selectbox" is compiled, and if i have 2 properties in the Message.Properties with the same type (e.g: 9) the generated id(of the html input created) is the same for both(although I'm generating it randomly), but I need different Ids of course for different inputs. I read that ng-repeat makes clones of the templates for each item, is that it?! How to solve it? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7):

You might be able to use `$index` inside your `ng-repeat` to create a unique id based on the current row. Taken from [the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat):

> Special properties are exposed on the local scope of each template
>   instance, including:
>
> - $index – {number} – iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)
> - $first – {boolean} – true if the repeated element is first in the iterator.
> - $middle – {boolean} – true if the repeated element is between the first and last in the iterator.
> - $last – {boolean} – true if the repeated element is last in the iterator.

Comment: thanks for the response but I've tried and it doesn't work in my case because i have certain logic in my code

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the conversion from your `Message.Properties` to the id is the problem. Have you tried to check this with explicitly setting the Properties to different sets of objects (even setting the `Message.Type` to something different than 9) and running this?

ng-repeat does not clone the template for each item, but does inherit the `$scope` from its parent so it might be that some objects from there are used in more than one item.